# Problems with pecl on ubuntu server

Tags: mongodb, pecl

I can`t install nothing with pecl in my Ubuntu 12 server.
Here the error:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongo
downloading mongo-1.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.3.2.tgz (120,931 bytes)
..........................done: 120,931 bytes
49 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
configure.in:36: error: AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE: requires a literal argument
aclocal.m4:124: PHP_CANONICAL_HOST_TARGET is expanded from...
aclocal.m4:1980: PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX_NAMES is expanded from...
configure.in:36: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you need to install php5-dev packageYou can do it by running 'apt-get install php5-dev' as a root userERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I already have installed php5-dev, m4 and phpize 
I also tried install mongo driver manually and happens the same error.
On line 36 in configure.in we have: PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX_NAMES

My PHP Version: PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 18:59:41)

Comment: So if you run phpize from the terminal it will find the program within your system path?

Comment: Yes, its intalled, here a output to help: https://gist.github.com/4551402
Also I tried to run sudo phpize on mongo driver directory but still the same :/

Comment: I must admit I am confused, pecl calls phpize just like the terminal does, hmm this sounds kinda noobie but I would try reinstalling phpize, pear and pecl and see if the problem goes away, it could be some faulty setup configuration

Comment: I would also suggest seeing if you can clone the [git repository](github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) and run `phpize && ./configure && make all`.